# XMLHttpRequest ResponseText is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xhtml

I’m having a devil of a time between XHTML, PHP, and JavaScript. My intent is to have a user select an option from a form menu and have that update the innerHTML of a DIV with the content of a separate PHP page. For instance, choosing "Cat" would call "animaloptions.php?species=cat", and the result of that would be thrown into the DIV block. However, if I specify the `Content-Type` of the calling page through PHP’s `Header` function, then my code fails.

The following is my JavaScript code:

```
function showOptions(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("mainArea").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }

    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if (xmlhttp) {
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "animaloptions.php", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8");

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("mainArea").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("mainArea").innerHTML = "Loading…";
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.send("species=" + str);
    }
}
```

This code works if I don’t include the following PHP code in the page that calls it:

```
header('Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8');
```

Doing so prevents the responseText from ever loading, presumably because readyState, status, or both don’t match the values I specified. If I don’t check for those conditions, then responseText is simply undefined.

My guess is asking PHP to send a raw HTTP header will prevent my XMLHttpRequest from functioning as expected. The problem is I need to send this raw header because the Web server is not identifying the page as UTF-8 on its own (thank you, unnamed Web host), and including the standard `<?xml version=1.0 encoding=utf-8 ?>` is impossible since my Web host turned on short tags in PHP. (Yes, I tried using `echo` to slap this into the page, but PHP automatically turns it into a commented line for some reason, which is a separate problem.)

Am I simply misusing XMLHttpRequest objects? Is there a practical way around this?

**EDIT**

I should have specified what I meant by “is not working”. In Safari's development tool, I see animaloptions.php added as a resource with code processed by PHP, but its contents are not added to the DIV block (or any block). If they were, then I would no longer see this page as a separate resource. If I use responseText in the JavaScript code, then the browser throws a DOM Error 12 (An invalid or illegal string was specified). If I use responseXML, then I get no error and no text, but animaloptions.php shows up under resources all the same.

Comment: Check the Net tab if your browser's developer tools. Is the response you expect being received?

Comment: Make sure "animaloptions.php" is the proper path, don't u need a "/" there? try to put a full URI i.e. `http://../animaloptions.php`

Comment: Absolute URIs are a good way to be bitten by same origin policies and sites with multiple hostnames (`www.example.com` and `example.com` as well public and development sites being the main examples).

Comment: I’ve updated my post with a response to Quentin’s comment. Just to be certain, I also tried an absolute URL, but the same results followed. I should also note I get the same results in Firefox, so I doubt this is a browser-specific issue.